# How to add condition in connection tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables: `Users` and `Images`.

So, a user can have some images.

For this relationship I have additional function in model `User`:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Images', 'idElement', 'id');
}
```

And in controller I have:

```
$users = Users::where('id', $id)->with("images")->get();
```

How can I add additional condition in controller for `images table` that will be `"where images.type = 1"`?

Now this tables are connected only by primary keys, but I need to set a new condition yet.

Comment: Sidenote: You have model `User` but you're accessing `Users::`. Model names should be singular (preference anyway)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter your images with callback function, try this:

```
$users = Users::where('id', $id)->with(["images" => function ($query){
    $query->where('type', 1);   
}])->get();
```

Comment: This condition will be applied for images table?

Comment: @Dev yes, for further information check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @Jose yes it will. Here you would be running a query against the images that relate to the user and only getting images where `type = 1`. It's a filter of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, where you want to scope down a subset of images based on their type, you can add another method called something like `public function scopedImages()` and define it as such:

```
public function scopedImages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Images', 'idElement', 'id')->where("images.type", "=", 1);
}
```

In your controller, you would access this function the same as you would the `images()` function on `User`:

```
$users = Users::where('id', $id)->with(["scopedImages"])->get();
```

Keep the function `images()` as well, so if you need to find all images attached to a `User`, but adding additional functions like this gives you flexibility on what you want to return and when.

Comment: How to pass param in function?